# C# WinForms How to add Panels with 100% width to FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, size, panels, flowlayoutpanel

I'm currently adding dynamically panels inside a flowlayoutpanel. The size of the panel is defined by the flowlayoutpanel width (flowlayoutpanel.clientsize.width). But as soon as I resize the GUI and the flowlayoutpanel gets bigger, the panel stays the same size. I tried to solve the problem with anchors but it didn't work out for me.

How can I keep the panel size same as the flowlayoutpanel size?

Picture of what I'm trying to achieve after resizing the window:

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the dock to fill? A picture would help to see what is going on and what you are intending.

Comment: easier with XAML  :P

Comment: @Ron Beyer i'll add a picture asap

Comment: @Michael Pucket II yes I know but I could choose to work with XAML since the project already was started with winforms

Comment: Resizing controls is a feature of TableLayoutPanel, surely what you intended to use when you make the child controls as wide as the panel.

Comment: @C.User Not a problem and I was just pulling your leg anyway. However; if the project is in .NET 3.5 or higher I would try adding a ```ElementHost``` to the WinForms, covering the entire view, then paste WPF views in it from there. I worked a legacy windows 8 embedded project and tried it and my team / supervision actually liked it and gave me permission to make the change. There's just so much more you can do with XAML and sometimes it just takes a demonstration. Anyway, if you're not using .NET 3.5+ or your team is hard against it then I feel your dilemma :(

Comment: Why wouldn't the anchors work? That's what they're for..

Comment: @TaW I don't know but the panel disappears when I add anchors to the panel.

Comment: Use `TableLayoutPanel` and set `DockStyle.Top` to panels.

Comment: thanks everyone for suggesting TableLayoutPanel but isn't it somehow possible to anchor the panel to the flowlayoutpanel?

Comment: Anchors don't go well with FlowLayoutPanel, which tries to do its own thing. If You could set the widths in the flp.Resize foreach of its Controls..

Comment: was able to solve it with tablelayoutpanel, thanks everyone for the quick answers!